# Recieve data when tableView is loading

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a simple like button. When a person presses the like button, the code is checking if the user already pressed *like* before. If not, it sends data to Firebase saying the user is liking this post, and it is then changing the `textColor` of the button to blue.

My problem is, when the user closes the app and opens it again, none of the buttons are blue. Even though the user liked several posts. I need some kind of code that can check if the user already liked the post and  change the `textColor` to blue when the `UITableViewController` is loading, I guess?

I tried to do that in my code, but it gets an error. So can anyone tell me how to go from here? My like button code:

```
func checkClickOnLikeButton() {
        let dataPathen = self.pathDB
        // print(dataPathen)


        if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {

            let userId = user.uid



            FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("feed-items").child(dataPathen).child("likesForPost").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
                // Get user value
                self.gottenUserId = snapshot.value![userId] as? Bool

                // print(self.gottenUserId)

                if self.gottenUserId == true {
                    print("Der er trykket high five før")
                } else {
                    print("Der er IKKE trykket like før")
                    let quoteString = [userId: true]
                    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("feed-items").child(dataPathen).child("likesForPost").updateChildValues(quoteString)
                    let blueButtonColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 122/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0)
                    self.highFiveButton.setTitleColor(blueButtonColor, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                }


                // ...
            }) { (error) in
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }



        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Id create a struct that fits your data. I would then keep the data you pull from the database locally in an array.

While building the table i.e cellForRowAtIndexPath, check indexPath.row against the value in your array to see if you've liked it. 
If you have liked it, i.e arrayOfUsers[indexPath.row].contains("myUserID"), then adjust your button to show already liked, and assign a number to the counter. Else, Do nothing.

Also - It wouldn't hurt to keep the query updated rather than doing observeSingleEventOfType(...), The reason I say this is you can then tell the query to persist data so even if the user closes app. launches your app on an iPad, and then goes back to the phone, the iPhone will be updated thanks to firebase.

So, to summarize that last bit, I would recommend changing the query not to observer once, and have it call specific functions when a child is removed / added